# Install Ubuntu 13.10 on MSI GS 70 Stealth - NVIDIA GTX 760 / Intel HD 4000

Tags: installation, dual-boot, uefi, msi

I recently bought an MSI GS 70 Stealth Notebook with Windows 8 preinstalled. I updated it to Windows 8.1 and reinstalled all the latest drivers and BIOS/firmware. I tried to install Ubuntu GNOME 13.10 after changing the boot mode from UEFI to Legacy (which also turns Secure Boot off).

First I tried to boot from the Live CD without installing. It gave me the Gnome logo with dots underneath but hung here and never changed. After looking around I found this site where apparently someone had got it working:

http://gs70-linux.blogspot.com/

I tried booting from the Live CD by replacing the `quiet splash` options with `nomodeset`. This worked and Ubuntu GNOME booted just fine and WiFi and everything else worked fine.

At this point I continued to install Ubuntu normally. It seemed to install correctly, when I rebooted I switched back to UEFI mode and tried to boot normally. I was greeted with grub. There was an entry for Ubuntu, but no Windows. I tried booting into Ubuntu and got only a blank screen. I tried restarting and editing the boot options at grub replacing `quiet splash` with `nomodeset` again, but this didn't work.

At this point I used to Live CD to boot back into Ubuntu and installed and ran the boot-repair utility. During some of the commands it had me copy into the terminal I got some warnings back:

```
source_dir doesn't exist. Please specify --target or --directory.

grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64; however, 
Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.
```

Even though I got these warnings it appeared the utility finished running successfully. It gave me the following URL: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6584972

It told me to make sure that it boots from `sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`.

After this I rebooted and switched back to UEFI. After rebooting normally I got grub again, this time with entries for Windows 8 and Windows recovery. I was able to boot into Windows 8 just fine. Ubuntu still hangs on a blank screen and doesn't load. If I hit the advanced options and try to select any of the ubuntu options it stops at `Loading initial ramdisk`. Trying to hit <kbd>e</kbd> and changing `quiet splash` to `nomodeset` doesn't change anything.

Anyone have any advice about what I can try next.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few more options to try to fix the video (?) problem:
Options for Video problems:

```
nomodeset
acpi=0
acpi_osi=linux
acpi_backlight=vendor
noalpic
i915.i915_enable_rc6=1
video=1280x1024-24@60
video=VGA-1:1280x1024-24@60
```

To allow Nvidia hybrid machines to boot.

```
nouveau.blacklist=1
```

To slow SSDs to allow them to boot:
libata.force=noncq